# WP_Query for getting posts under custom taxonomy not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode

I am trying to get custom post types from a custom taxonomy. Following the documentation and other similar problems related here, i did the following:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'job',
  'tax_query' => array(

     'taxonomy' => 'location',
     'field' => 'slug',
     'terms' => 'california'
   )
)
```

But the problem is that this query is getting all posts, not just posts under "California" taxonomy.

If more information is needed, i can provide more code editing the question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    $posts_array = get_posts(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'job',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'location',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'california',
          )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Didn't work also. It's bringing all the 'jobs', not only from 'california' :/

Comment: In fact, you suggested my tax_query as an array of arrays.. so i will considered this correct too!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an array. The tax query argument can be used for multiple taxonomies. It accepts an array of arrays.

> Important Note: tax_query takes an array of tax query arguments arrays
>   (it takes an array of arrays). This construct allows you to query
>   multiple taxonomies by using the relation parameter in the first
>   (outer) array to describe the boolean relationship between the
>   taxonomy arrays.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Change this:

```
'tax_query' => array(

     'taxonomy' => 'location',
     'field' => 'slug',
     'terms' => 'california'
   )
```

To this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'location',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'california',
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That confused me. Now it's working perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

In your while loop, remember to switch

```
<?php

  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
     $query->the_post();   
      // Important line, especially if you have
      //multiple WP_Query  invocations

     DO WHAT YOU WANT HERE

  wp_reset_postdata();
  }

 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my loop was correct... i reviewed it ;)

Comment: Glad u found a solution